# Does ACPI S3 suspend/sleep make Windows flush/sync filesystems?

Tags: windows, filesystems, suspend

I wonder if suspending a Windows machine (into ACPI S3 suspend/sleep state) includes a step in which windows flushes its buffers and `sync` the filesystem, so that the on disk representation is valid (i.e. not corrupted)

Most linux systems (e.g. android phones, linux servers and desktops) can enter power-save/suspend states. Before doing this in most cases the filesystems are flushed and `sync` with the on disk representation. This means that the on filesystems contain the latest data + metadata and if power was lost during the suspend state, a reboot would not require a filesystem check/repair.

I wonder if the same is true for Microsoft Windows OSes

Comment: Just because buffers are flushed doesn’t mean the filesystem doesn’t need repairs (it is not unmounted!) or application data isn’t corrupt.

Comment: @DanielB Would your remark implicitly contradict this answer https://superuser.com/a/1626464/160771 provided?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way for it to work - any sleep state can last an unlimited time
and a power-cut is always a possibility.

If the S3 state is interrupted by power loss, the disk is never damaged.
Only the running processes are lost in mid-work.

Windows is a robust operating system on equal footing with Linux in most areas.

Comment: I have to confess I was hoping for an answer that would suggest as does yours, that in-volantile-ram-memory filesystem data is flushed to the on harddisk representation of the filesystem. Now in the case of open source OS I would assume any idea about what happens on suspend can be derived looking at the open source code. How do you come to the conclusion that Windows is indeed rubost? Did you run a tests, or have access to the source code?

Comment: My conclusion is based on experience, mine, my colleagues and our clients.

Comment: thanks @harrymc for sharing that experience with us.